# Outbound Message field value OMMITTED

Tags: custom-field, workflowoutboundmessage

We have a custom field in the account object which is being received in the Outbound Message endpoint with a OMMITTED value, but in the Salesforce UI the field has a value. This had been working OK and it stopped suddenly.

Not sure if this has anything to do with the problem, mostly because we aren't sure when it stopped working, but some of the things made before the problem showed were:

1. Inactivated owner user
2. Deleted and recreated OM

Comment: So, what can we do to assist you with this omitted field value? What have you tried in your troubleshooting efforts so far?

Comment: What are the type of fields whose values are omitted in received outbound message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved, it was a DateTime value, we were trying to write it's value to a log file and were getting OMMITTED when passing it to the String.Format method. The solution was to add a casting and also check the HasValue property of the Nullable object. Something like this:

```
DateTimeField.HasValue ? ((DateTime)DateTimeField).ToShortDateString() : DateTime.MinValue.ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: Glad you found it because there was no way the community would have got to that answer given the details in your question.....